# sed + replace string/word and ignore space after string

Tags: sed

I use the following sed syntax in order to replace the timezone string with #timezone

actually sed command replace it , 
but in case after timezone string we have one space or more then sed not replaced it

my question what I need to change in the sed syntax in order to replace the timezone string 
on the both cases

1. After timezone string we not have any space
2. After timezone string we a have space or more

   ```
   sed -i '/timezone$/s/timezone/#timezone/' file
   ```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that 'timezone' only appears once per line? As written, you check that the line ends with 'timezone', then replace the first occurrence of 'timezone' with '#timezone'. It seems a little strange (but entirely possible).

Comment: yes , remark - the timezone is a function - so its appear only one per line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/timezone ?$/#timezone/' file
```

you need to add the `?` after a space, that will make the space optional. Also you'll have to add the `-r` option to make sed understand extended regex.

Also you are not specifying the backup extension after the `-i` option.

Comment: @David thx condaddict for the great solution , any way I not need backup because its small change , but its good to learn new things from you -:)

Comment: `?` is only zero spaces or one, the question asks about "one space or more". BTW, it is possible to use `\?` with GNU sed BREs (`-r` suggesting GNU sed).

Answer (score 0):

Stating your two cases as one, you want to replace 'timezone' followed by zero or more spaces, when it is at the end of the line. That should be this:

```
sed -i 's/timezone *$/#timezone/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be an ideal solution for both your cases.

```
sed 's/timezone *$\|timezone/#&/' INPUT_FILE
```